# Why are we so concerned about 1/2 of 1% (Golden Calf episode)

Tags: number, evil-resha, parashat-ki-tisa, golden-calf-egel

We just read (in Parshat Ki Tisa) that the Levites punished the 3,000 men who took part in the golden calf episode.  But 3,000 is only 1/2 of 1% of the 600,000 Israelite men who left Egypt. Why is the golden calf episode so important to our tradition if it involved such a tiny proportion of the people?  Is there commentary on this?

Comment: the majority should have stopped them,areivim zeh lazeh

Comment: 3000 were killed by sword.  Then there was a plague.

Comment: how would you feel if a doctor told you that ... had cancer in 0.0005% of your body!! we are one body, and every single stray Jew is a calamity for us all. let us all merit teshuvah shlaimah!

Answer (score 8):

The [Ramban to Shemos 32:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%91#.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7_.D7.96_.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A7.29.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7.29) explains that there were multiple tiers of sinners in the golden calf episode, all of whom had different intentions of varying degrees of infraction, but that it was the majority of the nation that sinned:

> אמר השם למשה כי עשו שתים רעות האחת כי שחת עמך וענין ההשחתה הריסת בנין... השני כי עשו עגל מסכה והשתחוו לו ויזבחו לו והנה העבירה הראשונה לא ידענה רק השם לבדו שהוא יודע תעלומות לב והשנית מעשה הזובחים החוטאים שבהם כאשר פירשתי והנה רוב העם חטאו במעשה העגל כי כן כתוב ויתפרקו כל העם את נזמי הזהב ולולי זה לא היה הכעס בכולם לכלותם והנה הנהרגים והנגפים מועטים כי ברובם היה החטא במחשבה רעה כמו שפירשתי
>
> (translation mine) Hashem said to Moshe that they had done two wrongs, the first was a matter of [spiritual destruction] and the second was the making of the calf and bowing and sacrificing to it.  The first is something that only Hashem knows its nature.  The second was the sacrificing.  **And most of the nation sinned with the calf**, as it is written "the entire nation took off their golden rings" and if not for that, Hashem would not have been upset at all of them to destroy them.  **Those killed and those struck in the plague were few**, as most of them sinned intellectually, as I explained.

The "as I explained" refers to the Ramban's commentary to verses 1 and 4, where he explains that they did not actually think the calf was G-d, and they wanted a replacement *leader* with the disappearance of Moshe.

Answer (score 1):

Many people beyond the 3000 killed by the Levi'im were guilty (and punished).  Yoma 66b records two views:

> It is stated: Rab and Levi are disputing in the matter. One said: Whosoever sacrificed and burned incense died by the sword; whosoever embraced and kissed [the calf] died the death [at the hands of Heaven]; whosoever rejoiced in his heart died of dropsy. The other said: He who had sinned before witnesses and after receiving warning, died by the sword; he who sinned before witnesses but without previous warning, by death; and he who sinned without witnesses and without previous warning, died of dropsy. (Soncino translation)

I found this passage via a note in the Stone *chumash*, which recorded only the latter view.  Whether this means *Chazal* rule that way elsewhere, or that the editors of the *chumash* chose the one they liked better, I do not know.

Either way, though, way more than 3000 people were punished, and the transgression itself was major and very public.  (I would think that it being *right there at the foot of Har Sinai, so soon after matan torah*, would also be relevant, but I don't have a source.)

Comment: Goiod find.  But how many died 0f these other punishments? Even if a nummber equal to or even twice the number killed by the Leviim, the total number involved in the idol worchip wouldb be very small, as a percent of the total.  (BTW, this page mentions a wise woman asking a question of Rabbi Eliezer.)

Comment: @YehudaW I didn't find a number.  (BTW, there's a [followup question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82957/472) about that, which is how I found my way to this question.)  Only 250 people died in Korach's rebellion and the torah tells us about that too, so maybe pure numbers aren't the key factor in determining if something is important enough for the torah to recount?